# Magento Setting Admin Configuration Values for Store View Scope via XML

Tags: magento

I have read many tutorials on how to define default values for configuration via XML and I think I have a grip on that, but we have several store views and I would like to also set default values at the store view level.  I am having a hard time finding anything out there that describes how to set a default value for anything other than the "default config" scope.  Do I just add a node to my XML that has the store view code in it? So instead of:

```
    <default>
<design>
    <email>
        <logo>
           <label>My Custom Logo</label>
        </logo>
    </email>
</design>
```

Would I do this?

```
    <my_store_view>
<design>
    <email>
        <logo>
           <label>My Custom Logo</label>
        </logo>
    </email>
</design>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this is because the store codes are arbitrary and can be changed any time in the database. You wouldn't want to have to keep changing the xml as the database is changed etc it doesn't maek sense

Comment: @Andrew, so are you saying there is no way to do it?  Is it possible to identify the store view by ID?  because those would never change...

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done i'm saying it doesn't make sense. default values or for when a store is just setup, but if it's just setup then you don't know the store code yet....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this  :

```
<stores>
    <your_store_code>
        <design>
            <email>
                <logo>value</logo>
            </email>
        </design>
    </your_store_code>
</stores>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason (when I use the default node, it works fine).  I am using Enterprise 1.12.

Comment: Can't test it under EE version (at least it worked for me on CE), but can you paste the code you tested and the code of your store view ?

Comment: @bImage I figured this out.  It DOES work.  I had entered a space in the field (I found out by checking the database) and saved it, so I created a new store view and tried this again and it worked.  Thank you very much!